# DataSet with many OR clauses

Tags: sql, visual-studio, dataset

I've got a little problem with a query which I create in the Visual Studio Designer.

I need a query with a lot of 'OR'-clauses for the same column.

I found the operator ['IN'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565%28SQL.90%29.aspx), but I don't know how to use that in the Visual Studio Designer:

Example `IN`:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, HireDate, City
FROM Employees
WHERE City IN ('Seattle', 'Tacoma', 'Redmond')
```

I tried to do it in this way:

```
SELECT [MachineryId], [ConstructionSiteId], [DateTime],
       [Latitude], [Longitude], [HoursCounter]
FROM [PositionData]
WHERE [MachineryID] IN @MachineryIDs
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there another way to handle a lot of `OR` clauses?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Check this SO question: [Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 1):

When doing an IN with a parameter it is used like below, fundamentally the same.

```
declare @SQL varchar(600)
set @SQL = 'select * from tbl where Cast([MachineryID] as varchar(255)) in ('+ @MachineryIDs +')'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Its very weird. When I try it with the @MachineryIDs parameter (and fill it with the values '1111','2222,'3333') it doesn't work. No rows are returned.
If I remove the @MachineryIDs parameter and write [MachineryID] IN ('1111','2222','3333') it works fine.

So there is something wrong with the parameter @MachineryIDs.

Did you have the same problem?

Thanks again ;)

Comment: when you are using the @MachineryIDs the query probably resolves to:
IN ('1111, 2222, 3333') - notice the ' only around the beginning and end of your string? It should be around every item in the list  IN('1111', '2222', '3333')